# Can someone help me out with why my object in javascript isn't being created?

Tags: javascript, html

I always seem to get errors with JS lint telling me that it was unable to finish.  I've included the script below.  Can someone please tell me why it isn't working?  I'm a newbe to javascript and I'm trying to catch up to speed but I am having issues with this.

```
<!Doctype html> doctype html
<head><br>head<br>script type="text/javascript" 
<script type="text/javascript"><br>
function President (name, number)<br>{
President.name = Obama;<br>
President.number = 44;<br>
President.name2 = Bush;<br>
President.number2 = 43;<br>
}

Var Obama = new President {"Barack H. Obama", 44};<br>
Var Bush = new President {"George W Bush", 43};<br>
</script>
</head>

/body tag<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(President.name + "loves" President.name2 + " because he is cool and is the " <br>

President.number2 " of the US ");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: WHy is there HTML in the JavaScript code?

Comment: You use of OO JavaScript is wrong.

Comment: Your HTML and JavaScript have a lot of errors. I don’t even know where to begin…

Comment: Where to begin...

Comment: Well, that's what I'm trying to figure out.  I obviously am having issues.

Comment: FYI the reason for the downvotes is because questions asking "Why doesn't this code work?" are off-topic for SO. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

You had many errors. See js fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Firstly, you cannot have `<br>` in your javascript. This is `html`.

Another thing is when you invoke a function you need to use `()` as opposed to `{}` - eg `new President("Barack H. Obama", 44);`

Inside the `President` function you should use `this` to refer to the variables within the function. i.e. `this.name = name;`.

When defining variables you need to use `var` in lowercase.

You have defined `President` with two arguments - name and number.

```
function President (name, number){...}
```

then when you create a new president the two arguments you passed are `"Barack H. Obama"` and `44`

```
new President("Barack H. Obama", 44);
```

```js
function President(name, number) {
  this.name = name;
  this.number = number;
}

var Obama = new President("Barack H. Obama", 44);
var Bush = new President("George W Bush", 43);

alert(Obama.name + " loves " + Bush.name + " because he is cool and is the " + Obama.number + " of the US");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of syntax issues with this code snippet. To get what you are trying to get you need to do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function President (name, number){
    President.name = name;
    President.number = number;
}

var Obama = new President("Barack H. Obama", 44);
var Bush = new President("George W Bush", 43);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(Obama.name + "loves" + Bush.name + " because he is cool and is the " + Obama.number " president of the US ");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

We don't use things like `<br>` and other HTML tags in JavaScript.

Also, we use () to call a function:

```
var Obama = new President("Barack H. Obama", 44);
var Bush = new President("George W Bush", 43);
```

Also, we need to use the keys on the prototype and use the values we passed in:

```
function President (name, number){
    President.name = name;
    President.number = number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<br>` tags can be implemented in javascript as follows:

```
var mybr = document.createElement('br');
someElement.appendChild(mybr);
```